# Accessing Facebook Marketing API (access token has permission issues on some ad accounts)

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have a facebook access token and have issues accessing ad accounts. For some ad accounts I can grab all information (insights/campaigns/adsets etc etc) but for some I receive the following error:

{"error":{"message":"(#274) The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add it in developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app -> settings -> advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account 170387XXXXXXXXX not enabled for this application.","type":"OAuthException","code":274,"fbtrace_id":"FwxE3u4w4Hh"}}

I am using the following command:
curl -G -d "fields=name" -d "access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_170387XXXXXXXXXX/adsets

please advise

Comment: This seems more like a question to ask the Facebook Support Team

Comment: Facebook support sends me here ...

Comment: With all due respect, I doubt Facebook Support told you "Go on StackOverflow.com and ask a Facebook-related question there"

Answer (score 0):

The error message basically says what you have to do:

"The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add it in developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app -> settings -> advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account 170387XXXXXXXXX not enabled for this"

Try going there and add the account id and see if it works. Also make sure that the user for whom the access token is issued has a role on all ad accounts you are trying to access.